# JQuery - download dynamically loadable site

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

If you want to download the html code of a site, you can use the .ajax (), like this

```
$.ajax({url: 'https://somesite.com'})
```

But what if the site uses lazy load? 
When you try to download site via .ajax, you get a page without dynamically loaded content.

Are there any way to get the html code for the site after it fully loads all the content?

Comment: I believe it has to be the same domain as you for this Ajax call to work https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Not if the target webserver sends correct CORS headers, for ex. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: Yes! I figured somesite.com, it was worth pointing out that you can't do it just for any site outside your control.

Answer (score 1):

You have to attach the loaded HTML to the DOM, then it will be parsed and any JS scripts will be executed which leads to lazy loaded content being downloaded.

```
$('.content').append(theDownloadedContent);
```